# Bash: Copy a folder full of files and folders to an external hdd, but only if there is enough space to complete the copy

Tags: bash, macos, file, copy

I want to copy a folder from my X-Serve RAID to an external HDD on an X-Serve. Both disks are on the same server, so copying is fairly easy. I use the ditto command:

```
ditto -rsrc /Volumes/WadXServeRaid/Users/ $destinationpath/Users/
```

However, I only want the copy to start if there is enough space on the destination disk. I know I can use the `DU` command to assess the destination disk but I don't know how to get the file size of a folder and compare it to the destination space.

Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

######Change These Vars######
srcFolder="/Volumes/WadXServeRaid/Users"
dstFolder="/path/to/some/external/folder/Users"
dstPartition="/dev/hdd1"
overheadbytes=104857600
#############################

dstBytes=$(df -B1 | awk -v dpart="$dstPartition" '$1 ~ dpart {print $4}');
read srcBytes _ < <(du -s "$srcFolder" 2>/dev/null);

if (( $dstBytes > $srcBytes + $overheadBytes )); then
  ditto -rsrc "$srcFolder" "$dstFolder"
fi
```

**Edit**

- Added $overheadBytes with default
  value of 100MB per comment discussion
- I didn't pass the partition/mount
  point as an argument to 'df' on
  purpose because it seems to require
  root privileges and I did not want to
  force such a script to be run as
  root.

Answer (score 2):

```
du -s name_of_folder_to_be_copied
```

will give you the total size of the folder and contained items (files and folders). With *df* you can check the free space on the destination drive. Compare the two sizes, and you're done (be carefull, *du* gives you the size in bytes, *df* in 512-bytes blocks, or 1024 bytes if you use the *-k* option).

Edit: to be more precise, you have to parse the *df* output. One way to only get the free space (in kB) on the destination disk could be:

```
df -k mount_point_of_destination|tail -1|sed "s/  */ /g"|cut -d ' ' -f 4
```

Mind you, you could achieve the same result with awk, for example. I just used sed and cut because that's the first way I thought off right off the bat ;)

Comment: I agree with the general idea. However, there will be trouble in the details, when the numbers are very close: If the destination filesystem has more per-file overhead, the copy might require significantly more space than the original.

Comment: Yes, that's true. One possible way to play it (almost) safe, would be to take the total size of the source folder and increment it by, say, 10% before comparing it to the free space on the destination disk. Obviously, the percentage would have to ideally be determined in such a way that it is high enough to be sure that there is enough space (even if some other user/program is writing to the destination disk), and at the same time low enough not to block a copy that would otherwise complete without error. Provided the fs is the same on both disk, it should pose no problem...